# Deriving the relativistic Larmor equation

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

I have derived the [Larmor equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula) as $$P = \frac{q^2}{6\pi \epsilon_0 c^3} |\ddot{r}|^2.$$

How do I make this relativistic?
Apparently, I have to consider the acceleration parallel and perpendicular to the velocity of the accelerating charge like: $$P = \frac{q^2}{6\pi \epsilon_0 c^3} (|\ddot{r}'_{\perp}|^2 + |\ddot{r}'_{\parallel}|^2).$$

But how does this lead to the answer: $$P = \frac{q^2}{6\pi \epsilon_0 c^3} \gamma^4(\gamma^2|\ddot{r}_{\perp}|^2 + |\ddot{r}_{\parallel}|^2).$$

I understand that parallel to the velocity, the will be relativistic effects, so where does this extra $\gamma^4$ come from?

Comment: See this reference: https://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/Class/phy319/phy319/node146.html , especially the part after 18.36 for the answer